# Mixing different bearer token types in OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

We are currently using OAuth bearer tokens in our applications. In REST calls those tokens are transported in the header, e.g. as

```
Authorization: Bearer xyz
```

In a new application we would like to use JWT. The problem is, that some of the new services will be called by both old and new applications, which of course will send different tokens (JWT vs. legacy tokens).

How should we distinguish the bearer tokens in these calls? The following options came to my mind:

1. Use the same endoint and same header. In this case the endpoint would have to look at the token and find out, if it is a legacy token or a JWT. But this doesn't seem to be bullet-proof.
2. Use the same endpoint but different authorization header for JWT. The endpoint reliably knows which token type is sent. But it's not standard.

   ```
   Authorization: Bearer-jwt xyz
   ```
3. Use the same endpoint and same header, with an additional token type header. Also not standard.

   ```
   Authorization: Bearer xyz
   X-Authorization-Bearer-Type: JWT
   ```
4. Use different endpoints. This would add a lot of extra work on deployment and governance, so I would like to avoid this option.

Any recommendations, or even another viable option?

Answer (score 1):

Option 3. seems a reasonable option and an alternative to that is to pass the token type as part of the query parameters, depending on what is easiest to implement.

Yet I would vote for 1. since a JWT can be identified by the 3 dots in `<header>.<payload>.<signature>` and the header must be a base64url encoded JSON object with an `alg` claim in it, that is a pretty safe way of distinguishing the two.